# copy a string into a TCHAR in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to copy a string into a TCHAR in C++ but I'm hit with the following error:

> Error C4996 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

This is what I'm trying to do. I'm just copying a string into a TCHAR and then attempting to print it out to confirm it's correct.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    string str = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";
    TCHAR *szAppName = new TCHAR[str.size() + 1];
    copy(str.begin(), str.end(), szAppName);
    _tprintf(szAppName);
}
```

EDIT
How do I "use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" as the message states?

Comment: *" To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS."*

Comment: BTW, `main` returns `int`, always.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're a bit condescending. I obviously read it. How do I "use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" ... that should have been in my question.

Comment: Simply add `#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before your `#include` statements, or add the `-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` flag to your project's compiler input flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as compiler warning says.  You can add `#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before your `#include` statements, or add the `-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` flag to your project's compiler input flags.

However, this is not a proper solution.  `std::copy()` is not adequate for converting a `char`-based string to a `TCHAR`-based string when `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t` instead of `char`.  Copying characters 1-to-1 only works for ASCII characters (which your example is using), but fails when non-ASCII characters are used, as the resulting `TCHAR[]` array may require more `TCHAR` elements than `str.size()` reports.  You really need to use a data conversion like `MultiByteToWideChar` or `std::wstring_convert` in that situation.

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef basic_string<TCHAR> TCHARstring;

TCHARstring string2TCHAR(const string &s)
{
    #ifdef UNICODE
    TCHARstring tstr;
    int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), str.length(), NULL, 0);
    if (size > 0)
    {
        tstr.resize(size);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), str.length(), &tstr[0], size);
    }
    return tstr;
    #else
    return s;
    #endif
}

int main()
{
    string str = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";
    TCHARstring tstr = string2TCHAR(str);
    _tprintf(_T("%s"), tstr.c_str());
    /*
    or:
    #ifdef UNICODE
    wcout << tstr;
    #else
    cout << tstr;
    #endif
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Or simpler (like @MicroVirus suggested):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef basic_string<TCHAR> TCHARstring;

int main()
{
    TCHARstring str = TEXT("C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe");
    _tprintf(_T("%s"), tstr.c_str());
    /*
    or:
    #ifdef UNICODE
    wcout << tstr;
    #else
    cout << tstr;
    #endif
    */
    return 0;
}
```

You really should stop using `TCHAR`, though.  Its primarily purpose was to help migrate legacy Win9x/ME ANSI code to NT4+ Unicode, by allowing developers to use a single codebase for both platforms.  Nobody develops for Win9x/ME anymore, though, so you should stick with Unicode for everything:

```
int main()
{
    wstring str = L"C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";
    wprintf(L"%s", str.c_str());
    // or: wcout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Or at least keep using `string` as-is and let the OS handle ANSI->Unicode conversions at the API layer (not recommended, but still supported):

```
int main()
{
    string str = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";
    printf("%s", str.c_str());
    // or: cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you have to do manual conversions when you want to use ANSI `string` values with Unicode APIs:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

wstring string2wstring(const string &s)
{
    wstring wstr;
    int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), str.length(), NULL, 0);
    if (size > 0)
    {
        wstr.resize(size);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), str.length(), &wstr[0], size);
    }
    return wstr;
}

int main()
{
    string str = "C:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";
    wstring wstr = string2wstring(str);
    wprintf(L"%s", wstr.c_str());
    // or: wcout << wstr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's for an operating systems class. I'm to modify legacy code. I would never write C++ if not for that reason alone. I appreciate your in depth assist.

Comment: BTW, the #define alone doesn't fix anything for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a *warning*, and it's only preventing compilation because you have set your compiler to treat warnings as errors.

The warning is overzealously pointing out that `szAppName` is just a pointer, and that it's up to *you* to ensure that there's enough space in the destination array for the copy result (which you've done) because failure to do so can cause spaceships to explode.

To disable the warning, do what the message says.

Or, y'know, stop using raw dynamically allocated arrays. Your original `std::string` was just fine. If you really wanted a `TCHAR*` to that data, you could have simply said `str.c_str()` (or `str.data()`). If you're using Unicode, you'd copy into, or begin with, a `std::wstring`.

Comment: Not if `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t` instead of `char`. In which case, `copy()` is not an adequate solution anyway to convert a `char`-based string to a `wchar_t`-based string. The resulting `TCHAR[]` array may require more `TCHAR` elements than `str.size()` reports. You need to use a data conversion like `MultiByteToWideChar` or `std::wstring_convert`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Then the OP should still be copying into a `std::wstring`, if anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

A 'trick' to using `TCHAR` in Windows along with the STL strings that I prefer to use is to define my own `tstring` type:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
```

Then, I use `tstring` instead of `std::string` everywhere. This way, if you compile using "Multi-Byte character set" for character set it is equal to `std::string` and when you compile using "Unicode character set" it is equal to `std::wstring`.

The great thing is that this avoids the need to copy it to a `TCHAR` array, and you can directly use its `c_str()` property with `_tprintf` and all other functionality in the *TCHAR.h* header. It also gets rid of the warning, which was pointing out a potential issue.

Answer (score 1):

Secure coding is enforced in modern compilers to improve code quality.

Early C designed a function like `gets( buffer );`  which read up to the new line into buffer.

This caused crashes in the program (buffer overflow), and then some people figured out they could "take over" the program, and allow a remote attacker to take over the computer.

Modern `C++` design has tried to offer the same sort of functionality, without risk of fixed sized buffers.

The complaint is that when copying into szAppName, the `std::copy` isn't able to check that `szAppName` is of sufficient size, and if it isn't, then your program is vulnerable.

In your case, you have created the buffer of the correct size, and the warning hasn't helped.

There is a different sort of vulnerability in the `_tprintf`.  This is meant to take a string with format specifiers and print out parameters.

Consider `_tprintf( "%s", szAppName ); // avoid _tprintf exploit.`
Also

```
_tprintf( "%s", str.c_str() ); // avoid copying buffer.
```

As that will avoid the warning.

Comment: By themselves, these don't remove the error. I think I still need to set the flag but thank you for pointing out the exploit and describing it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot shows where to add the compiler option flag. It's in Project properties > C/C++ > Command Line. Add `-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` under additional options.

[image]